# Searching in Active Directory for a user with a given login in a given group

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, active-directory

How can I construct a filter for DirectorySearcher to check if there is a user with a given login in a given group?

```
$ "(sAMAccountName = {login})";
```

Something like this (searching only by login) works for me, but I have no idea how to add the condition that the user should only search in one selected group, and not search the entire AD.
I tried:

```
$ "(& (objectClass = user) (sAMAccountName = {login}) (memberOf = [{groupDistinguishedName}]))"
```

And these types of constructs, but in FindOne () it always gets null ...
As groupDistinguishedName I gave the name in the format "CN = GroupName, CN = ..., DC = ..., DC = ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple potential issues I see. First, there shouldn't be any square brackets `[]`. Also, in your example group distinguished name, you have spaces. Maybe that's just how you typed it in your question, but the real value should not have any spaces (around `CN=` for example). It should exactly match what's in the `distinguishedName` attribute of the group.

The complete filter should look something like this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=SomeUser)(memberOf=CN=groupName,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com))
```

Comment: Thanks works! Maybe I didn't notice and I had some spaces.